# Comparing two ByteArrayOutputStreams in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, outputstream

I'm writing output to an excel file which is being written through `ByteArrayOutputStream`. I want to write test for comparing the expected `ByteArrayOutputStream`(whether the excel cell contains the data as I required) with the output `ByteArrayOutputStream` .Is there a way to compare two `ByteArrayOutputStreams` in `Java` ? Also how should I set my expected outputStream ?

Answer (score 4):

You can compare their content by doing something like this:

```
Arrays.equals(byteArrayOutputStream1.toByteArray(), byteArrayOutputStream2.toByteArray());
```

You can set its content like any other `OutputStream` thanks to the `write` methods if the content is big, but If your expected value is small, the better approach will be to put the content into a `String` variable then do the next test instead of the previous one:

```
Arrays.equals(expectedContent.getBytes(myCharset), byteArrayOutputStream2.toByteArray());
```

Comment: How should I set the expected ByteArrayOutputStream ?

Comment: I'm not able to visualize how should I set the expected content. Suppose I'm expecting to have 2 row and 2 column of excel. The data should be like : (1,1) = Name, (1,2) = Type, (2,1) = LinkedList, (2,2) = List. So how should I write this as String ?

Comment: @Ashley I'm not able to visualise what part of this answer you don' understand.

Comment: How to set the expected content which is an excel file as a String ? The output will be an xlsx file in ByteArrayOutputStreamFormat which I can convert to byte array. I want to unit-test (or assert against ) this output byte Array with the expected one.

Comment: @Ashley dealing with Excel is not really your initial question, you should ask in another question but first you can check apache poi and this https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents

Comment: @Ashley If my answer is good enough for you don't hesitate to up vote and/or to mark it as best response, thx in advance